# OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/glob/intel-python/versions/2018u2/intelpython3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docs' on intel dev cloud

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip, cloud, conda

I am unable to install packages in my intel dev cloud. I tried installing packages using pip from bash shell. I also created a new conda environment and tried installing packages there. It didn't work either. I think the problem is with permissions in file system. The error says "read-only file system" as you can see.

Any suggestions can greatly help.

P.S: I am trying to install keras and sklearn

please check the error log below.

```
Installing collected packages: keras
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/glob/intel-python/versions/2018u2/intelpython3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/glob/intel-python/versions/2018u2/intelpython3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/glob/intel-python/versions/2018u2/intelpython3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/glob/intel-python/versions/2018u2/intelpython3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/glob/intel-python/versions/2018u2/intelpython3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/glob/intel-python/versions/2018u2/intelpython3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/glob/intel-python/versions/2018u2/intelpython3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/glob/intel-python/versions/2018u2/intelpython3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/glob/intel-python/versions/2018u2/intelpython3/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/glob/intel-python/versions/2018u2/intelpython3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docs'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the guidance of @J_H I found out the answer.

`pip` usually tries to install packages globally, which is not allowed on shared platforms like Intel DevCloud. Hence we need to install packages for single user that is you.

Hence

```
pip install --user keras
```

installs keras in your home directory and you are not restricted to write in your home directory. Problem Solved!

Answer (score 0):

> I think the problem is with permissions in file system. The error says "read-only file system"

Yes, you correctly diagnosed the problem.

You need to choose a writable filesystem to write the installed files to.

You may find the `df` and `mount` commands helpful. Start with `man df`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since I am using intel dev cloud, I am limited to use single partition which is allocated to me by the admins. I think by default, pip is trying to install the packages globally which is restricted. So I think, I need to setup a runtime in the partition allocated to me, install my packages there and make my project use that runtime. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Consider using `conda` to run pip for you. It will keep libs nicely organized under ~/miniconda/envs/my_project. https://conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html